# Top xx% "more" default display bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

The "xx% more" links at the top of the profile defaults to the full list being shown, instead of just the first line:

[image: more bug]

Clicking the link results in it collapsing to the expected default view:

[image: more expected]

Clicking again results in the full list displayed and the link changes to "fewer":

[image: fewer expected]

With some profiles, in particular for high rep users, this looks... busy.

---

Update:

This seems to have been sorted now. Can someone please change the status to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) if it has been intentionally fixed?

Comment: Thanks Oded, yes the bug was confirmed and fixed.